# Regarding zeros of f

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f $ be a meromorphic function such that $ |f(z)|≥|z|$ at each $ z$, where f is holomorphic.

How can we conclude from the above information that $ f$ has no zeros, except possibly at the origin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(z)=0$ then $|z| \leq |f(z)|=0$ so $z=0$.